# Open terminal tab NEXT to current (active) tab

Tags: gnome-terminal, tabs, xfce4-terminal

I want to be able to open a new tab in the current terminal window, but have that new tab come up right next to the current one (on the right of it) rather than at the very right of the tabs.

Is this possible?

Comment: This should be the default behavior :-)

Comment: @Morten unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: I know but it should be ... in my humble opinion anyway  :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with current gnome-terminal. If you're not afraid of recompiling it from source, well, there's a patch available at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709109.

Comment: How often does the gnome-terminal update? I'm wondering how often I will need to recompile it in order to maintain this feature after every update.

Comment: It's unlikely to get updated within a particular Ubuntu release. So with a little bit of luck you should be good for half a year (assuming you're on Vivid now and upgrade when a new release is made).

Comment: Ideally you should figure out how to recompile an Ubuntu package and follow this procedure. This would result in .deb packages that you can replace the official ones with. I'm not quite familiar with that process though. If you choose to compile/install manually and overwrite the files installed by the package, you should probably download the same version as shipped by Ubuntu, and do a `./configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib/gnome-terminal --enable-distro-packaging && make && sudo make install`. Assuming Vivid, you might also want to apply the transparency patch from Ubuntu package.